# What's wrong with this ForEach loop?

Tags: c#, foreach

Yep... it's one of those days.

```
public string TagsInput { get; set; }

//further down
var tagList = TagsInput.Split(Resources.GlobalResources.TagSeparator.ToCharArray()).ToList();
tagList.ForEach(tag => tag.Trim()); //trim each list item for spaces
tagList.ForEach(tag => tag.Replace(" ", "_")); //replace remaining inner word spacings with _
```

Both ForEach loops don't work. tagList is just a List.

Thank you!

Comment: Please don't say they "don't work".  Please describe what you expected to happen, and what you actually observed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Trim()` and `Replace()` don't modify the string they're called on. They create a new string that has had the action applied to it.

You want to use `Select`, not `ForEach`.

```
tagList = tagList.Select(t => t.Trim()).Select(t => t.Replace(" ", "_")).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

ForEach (and other "linq" methods) does not modify the list instance.

```
tagList = tagList.Select(tag => tag.Trim().Replace(" ", "_")).ToList();
```

Comment: I do not believe `ForEach` is a LINQ method...it is a List<T> method. And I DO believe that ForEach is an action that is applied to each item at the time it is invoked...

Comment: @jrista - it's not a linq method.  That's why it's in quotes.

Comment: Right...however, it DOES apply the action immediately, its not delayed.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is string is immutuable. So the result of each Trim() or Replac() function will produce a new string. You need to reassign to the original element in order to see the updated value.

Comment: This is good also... providing the reason why it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly why Microsoft havent implemented ForEach on an IEnumerable.  What's wrong with this?

```
public string[] TagsInput { get; set; }

//further down
var adjustedTags = new List<string>();
foreach (var tag in TagsInput.Split(Resources.GlobalResources.TagSeparator.ToCharArray()))
{
    adjustedTags.Add(tag.Trim().Replace(" ", "_"));
}

TagsInput = adjustedTags.ToArray();
```

Comment: thankyou, someone with some actual sense. although you dont need the expense of a List, you know how many elements you have.

Comment: This is ok too. I like it. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

If by don't work, you mean that they don't actually do anything, I think you need to adjust your code a bit:

```
public string TagsInput { get; set; }

//further down
var tagList = TagsInput.Split(Resources.GlobalResources.TagSeparator.ToCharArray()).ToList();
tagList.ForEach(tag => tag = tag.Trim()); //trim each list item for spaces
tagList.ForEach(tag => tag = tag.Replace(" ", "_")); //replace remaining inner word spacings with _
```

Trim and Replace don't change the value of the string, they return the new string value.

Comment: Yes, but here you just replace a local loop-var. I don't think this solves anything. The Analysis is right though.

Comment: True. Analysis is correct, the code produces the same result as mine.